# A* functionality

Tags: algorithm, search, shortest-path, a-star

I'm just after some clarification how A* for path finding should operate in the [case] of two paths having equal value, both during the calculation and also at the end if there are two equal short paths.

For example I'm at my start node and there are two possible nodes I can expand to, but they both have the same f(x). Do they both get expanded and in which order?

What happens if at the end of the search there are two equal shortest paths?

Comment: Pick a random one? Do you have any other data regarding the paths (risk, benefits, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you just pick an arbitrary one. Note that A* finds one of the shortest paths, not all of them, and no specific way of resolving ambiguities like those that you described is necessary for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your own implementation of A* you get to decide exactly how such cases would be handled. Typically, whichever of the equal shortest paths is *current* at the moment when the algorithm determines that all remaining paths are *at least as costly* will be returned as **the** shortest path.

In my game program (on hex grids) I use have two separate implementations of A*. One for short distances (and without road movement) uses a vector product as tie-breaker between equal paths, that chooses the one which is *visually more direct*. The one for longer distances enables road movement and ignores the refinement above, but uses a more complicated heuristic that is much more efficient over long ranges.

There are many questions on [Game Development StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) that address various refinements of the A* algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

A good heuristic will evaluate on many conditions (add probabilistic conditions such as risk, cost, utility management, rationality of the operation, etc) and thus will minimize the number of shortest path.

However, if there are still multiple paths on the **fringe (i.e. array of expandable nodes)**, a simple A* will pick up arbitrarily.